# Save session in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am new to python Pycharm IDE.

When I close the application, I need to again run entire code to data frames.
I know in R we can save session so that we should not run entire code again.

Comment: I don't believe PyCharm can help you out here. You might want to take a look at https://ipython.org/